# Azure ad and Azure ad b2c token validation failure

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Azure ad B2c development Web app,I want use the graph api (msgraph) to get and set the user's group.So,I create a azure ad b2c service name is B2Ctest,and B2CTest based azure ad service name is Adtest.

I use this api [Microsoft Graph Client Library for .NET](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) and used Adtest setting msgraph.

I get the B2Ctest service's user token, and  passing the token to msgraph get the user own's group.It's throw a exception.

I catch msgraph post http packet.

address:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups

response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "e715c5f9-5c2c-40d8-ad09-71c848205d2c",
      "date": "2017-10-09T16:10:20"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This clearly indicates that you did not acquire the token correctly, the token i not valid. You should investigate the token generation part.

Answer (score 1):

[aad b2c access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFvWn.png)

[aad access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42kuD.png)

I found,that aad b2c access token and aad access token are not the same.